# Putting TOP 3 into separate columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Lets say there's a table with column `animals`:

```
-- animal --
   dog
   dog
   dog
   giraffe
   cat
   cat
   mouse
   mouse
   elephant
```

What's the best way to create a result set based on the TOP 3 animals that appear the most?  It has 3 separate columns, 1 for each animal.

Result set:

```
-- animal 1 -- animal 2 -- animal 3 --
   dog         cat         mouse
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then animal end) as animal_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then animal end) as animal_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then animal end) as animal_3       
from (select animal, count(*) as cnt, row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by animal
     ) a
```